# How to get the control under the mouse cursor in onMouseDown event?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, mousedown, mouse-position, childcontrol

I have a TGridLayout filled with some images in a **Firemonkey HD Application**. In the gridLayout's onMouseDown event I want to get the image object on which the user has clicked, but I have only mouse coordinates.

Implementing onMouseDown event for every image is not an option, because if an image is removed from the gridlayout an empty space remains. In this case I also want to know if the user has clicked in this empty area.

Is there a some kind of "getChildAtPos" or "FindVCLWindow" analog in **Firemonkey**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TForm.ObjectAtPoint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ObjectAtPoint) should do the trick.

Comment: ha ha. Emba had to rename the function because it contained VCL in its name :)

Answer (score 0):

[FindVCLWindow](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_FindVCLWindow.html) does what you need. You need to specify the point at which the control is, in your case it's mouse position.

Comment: The question was about FireMonkey!

Comment: My fault also :) I refined the question so it's clear now it's about Firemonkey Application.